# How to create a .csv file from 4 folders containing 100 files each in R?

Tags: r, file, csv

How to create a large .csv file from 4 folders containing 100 files each, using an R code? The individual files in the 4 folders are not .csv files but normal files. I don't know how to create this and can't find any answers online, for reference my large folder `Newsgroups(D:/Newsgroups)` contains 4 folders `(D:/Newsgroups/1)`, ..., `(D:/Newsgroups/4)`. Within each of the 4 folders, there are 100 files `(D:/Newsgroups/1/100)`. My main goal with the final .csv file is to create a bag of words.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is possible to do in R, but in order for us to help you we would need an example of one of the files. If you can provide a small snippet of what is contained in the files, we can help you write the code. By "normal files" do you mean plain text files?

Comment: @qdread, yes plain text file, i will include example of one file: "Newsgroups: sci.electronics
In article <1993Mar25.161909.8110@wuecl.wustl.edu> dp@cec1.wustl.edu (David Prutchi) writes:
>In article <C4CntG.Jv4@spk.hp.com> long@spk.hp.com (Jerry Long) writes:
>>Fred W. Culpepper (fculpepp@norfolk.vak12ed.edu) wrote:
>>[...]
>>A couple of years ago I put together a Tesla circuit which
>>was published in an electronics magazine and could have been
>>the circuit which is referred to here. This one us.." just contains words and numbers in each text file, thanks for your help